# I can't seem to get my navigation styles to work. They work while editting in the developer tools on chrome, but it doesn't work upon saving

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have been making a navigation bar, using inspector to preview my changes.

When I use the inspector, the following code works:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ><a href='dashboard.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href='trainer.php'>Trainers</a></li>
    <li ><a href='https://www.irijobs.com/webmail'>E-Mail</a></li>
    <li ><a href='report.php'>Reports</a></li>
    <li ><a href='change-password.php'>Change Password</a></li>
    <li ><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
<ul>
    <li ><a href='dashboard.php'>Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href='trainer.php'>Trainers</a></li>
    <li ><a href='https://www.irijobs.com/webmail'>E-Mail</a></li>
    <li ><a href='report.php'>Reports</a></li>
    <li ><a href='change-password.php'>Change Password</a></li>
    <li ><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the only code in both files (besides headers of course).

As mentioned, the styles worked perfectly fine while editing in the inspector. I have copied all that CSS and saved it in my CSS file.

What is interesting, is once I saved the CSS file and reloaded the webpage, all the styles for the unordered list seems to disappear, even though they should work perfectly fine. In a previous edit of this question, the snippets worked as well. I have repeated this error from scratch 5 times now.

The following are screenshots to help show the issue.

[How the code looks in snippets and while editing in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lpZR.png)
and
[How it looks after pasting and saving the CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNyI6.png)

What else is interesting is if I were to copy the CSS from the inspector in photo 1, and then paste it into the inspector in photo 2, there are no changes to the styling (aka it is still not working properly), which doesn't make sense since it worked perfectly fine when I created the code. It seems that the ONLY styles not recognized are the unordered lists.

Here is an example in firefox, as you can see; the CSS is technically correct, yet is not displayed.

[Firefox example- Note that this is all from files saved on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BExN.png)

When inspectint the ul element, here is all I receive for styles:

[Styles used according to Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOJu5.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *"upon saving"*? How exactly do you save what you code in inspector?

Comment: I copy the developer area and paste it to the CSS file, I save the CSS file and reload. It's worth noting that if I paste thecode back into the developer area, it still comes out messed up. So far, I have deducted it is the <ul> tag that is not being styled, everything else is styled correctly.

Comment: You should note coding in inspector does not change your CSS file. You are supposed to copy/paste whatever you coded in the inspector in the CSS file before saving. Coding in inspector is just a way to preview changes. It's not part of an integrated development system with whatever tools you're using for editing your files. The inspector also tells you what rules apply to each element, so you can easily see what's overriding your rules. You should probably also pay close attention to the selectors being used.

Comment: Edited my comment and question to address that.

Comment: As you can see, it works. You're either not loading that CSS in your page or there are more specific rules applying. Either way, we can't help you until you reproduce the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for helping me be a little more clear; hopefully The above question edit is more helpful.